# OS X 10.9 blue screen on startup

Tags: macos, startup

I installed the last version of VMware Fusion on my MBP 15″ 2011 and had 2 kernel panics. It restarted well and did it again a few hours later. Now it won't boot.

I tried to repair disk via SU mode using `fsck -yf`. It succeeded, but still not able to boot. I also try to boot on Recovery partition but it failed, blue screen too.

I don't know what to do, I unmounted the SSD and tested it on another machine — I can see all my files.

The Boot Camp partition doesn't work either.

Comment: VMware Fusion is normally very stable, I have not had problems running it on Mac OSX 10.7, 10.8, or 10.9.  Which version of VMware are you running, and on which version of Mac OSX?

Comment: @Deesbek 10.9, last vwmare fusion

Comment: What happens when you try a Safe Boot (not the same thing as booting single-user mode)?

Comment: @da4 With `shift` pressed? doesn't work neither

Comment: If you have another Mac available, try restarting your MBP into Target Disk Mode by holding down T immediately after bootin, then connect via FireWire and run Disk Utility from the other Mac.  This sounds like disk corruption not specifically related to VMWare.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The system was good, the motherboard over, Apple changed it.